# session data is not pass (php)

Tags: php

i have created a session after my login page and wanted to redirect to a secure page with session i created earlier.. but my session data is not pass.. may i know wat is the problem..

php session:

```
    $em = $_POST['email'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];
$em = mysql_real_escape_string($em);
$pw = mysql_real_escape_string($pw);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Register WHERE email = '$em' AND pass = '$pw'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());  

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['login']=$em;

//echo 'Connected';
// Jump to secured page
echo "<script>window.location='http://example.com/secure.php'</script>";
}
```

the page i redirected to:

```
   <?php session_start(); $_SESSION['login']; ?>
   <p>Welcome 
   <?php
   //retrieve session data
   echo $_SESSION['login'];
   ?> 
   to M-Cloud</b>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the value of $em right before you store the session data? Without the full script, I can't tell if there is a problem with $em at that point. Also, calling $_SESSION['login'] right after session_start() in the second block of code is not needed, and might be the source of the problem.

Comment: What happens before `mysql_num_rows()`?

Comment: i hav updated the part here.. TQ

Answer (score 3):

Firstly.

Make sure that the session_start is at the top of the pages. That is the best practice.

Make sure the $em has a value when the SESSION is being set.

Check that the web hosting you use supports SESSIONS.

And at the top of the second page, you don't need to have the $_SESSION['login']; bit

To test that $em definitely has a value. echo it out on that page to check.

If this does not work, please paste more of the code so we can find the problem.

Comment: i get this error msg.. Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /www/zymichost.com/m/y/c/mycloud/htdocs/login.php:6) in /www/zymichost.com/m/y/c/mycloud/htdocs/login.php on line 7

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /www/zymichost.com/m/y/c/mycloud/htdocs/login.php:6) in /www/zymichost.com/m/y/c/mycloud/htdocs/login.php on line 7

Comment: Put ob_start(); at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first `$_SESSION['login'];` on the second page, then show the whole `$_SESSION` array with `print_r($_SESSION);` to see if the value is correct or not.